# Show only newest database table content

Tags: php, mysql, database

I like to display only the newest database table entry on my website. The connection to the database with PHP is working and it is showing the table content but not the newest. Is there an easy way to get only the newest entry displayed in HTML?

Some background information about the project:

The database collects the data from an ESP with a door sensor (Arduino) and I only need the active status of the sensor (open or closed). The table has one column and the database prints automatically the status (1 or 0) in the table.

```php
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=smarthome', test, '');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM doorsensor ORDER BY status LIMIT 1";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) 
   echo $row['status']."<br />";
?>
```

Comment: Can you please post the table structure?

Comment: _The table has one column_ you can't accomplish this without an AI ID or something like a timestamp. You should add an auto increment ID and set that as Primary Key, then set the old attribute as _unique_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your identifier column is called `id` and also you are looking for status' with value 1? Then your query should be this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM doorsensor WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `id` column with `auto_increment`, you can use this;

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM doorsensor ORDER BY status WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM doorsensor)";
```

This should work for you!

Comment: What makes you think that the "newest" content is the one with highest ID? Additionally, the OP stated that the table currently has exactly one column containing a status